# JMSSerializerBundle, how to choose alternative config file

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using JMS serializer as the JMSSerializerBundle for Symfony2.

I serialize my entities this way :

```
$this->serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');
$json = $this->serializer->serialize($values, 'json');
```

The bundle use automatically the ref config that match the bundle/entity name :

```
MyBundlePath/Resources/config/serializer/Entity.Name.yml
```

In my case, i need to provide two different configuration for the same entity class, is there any way to specify which yml/xml file to use to the serializer ?

**Edit**:
nifr provided the solution, the group features

In my YAML conf case, you just need to add the groups param

```
Entity.ClassName:
    ...
    properties:
        some-property:
            ...
            groups: [first, second]
```

Then specify it in the serialize call :

```
$serializer->serialize($values, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('my-group-name')));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what [serialization groups](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#creating-different-views-of-your-objects) are meant for. They're similar to [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups) in the validator component.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that in the doc, exactly what i was looking for. Thx